# Regex deleting all lines except last occurence of a pattern

Tags: regex, vim

I want to delete all lines that match a pattern but the last occurrence.
So assume we have this text:

```
test a 043
test a 123
test a 987 
test b 565
```

The result I'm aiming for is this:

```
test a 987 
test b 565
```

Is it possible to compare strings like that with just regex in vim? This is also assuming the `a` and `b` in this example are dynamic (`(test\s\w\s(.*)`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need a lookahead regex in vim for this:

```
:g/\v(^test \w+)(\_.*\1)@=/d
```

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
\v            # very magic to avoid escapes
(             # capturing group #1 start
   ^test \w+  # match any line starting with test \w+
)             # capturing group #1 end
(\_.*\1)@=    # positive lookahead to make sure there is at least one of \1 below
```

Comment: very nice usage of look ahead with dynamic length! +1

Comment: That looks right thanks. Can you explain what `\_` and `@=` do in this case, please?

Comment: @F.Rakes If I were you, i will first try `:h \_. and :h \@=`

Comment: Very interesting, I didn't know of those, thanks @Kent.